# Who was the biggest "Weekend Update" host during that time period?

Tags: code-golf, date, search

These are the hosts of the "Weekend Update" news segment on *Saturday Night Live*, with the years they hosted and their initials:

```
Chevy Chase         1975-1976  CC
Jane Curtain        1976-1980  JC
Dan Aykroyd         1977-1978  DA
Bill Murray         1978-1980  BM
Charles Rocket      1980-1981  CR
Gail Matthius       1981       GM
Brian Doyle-Murray  1981-1982  BD
Mary Gros           1981-1982  MG
Christine Ebersole  1982       CE
Brad Hall           1982-1984  BH
Christopher Guest   1984-1985  CG
Dennis Miller       1985-1991  DM
Kevin Nealon        1991-1994  KN
Norm MacDonald      1994-1997  NM
Colin Quinn         1998-2000  CQ
Jimmy Fallon        2000-2004  JF
Tina Fey            2000-2006  TF
Amy Poehler         2004-2008  AP
Seth Meyers         2006-2014  SM
Cecily Strong       2013-2014  CS
*Colin Jost         2014-pres  CJ
*Michael Che        2014-pres  MC

*At the time of this writing, present is 2017.
```

I got most of the years [this website](http://www.saturday-night-live.com/history/weekendupdate.html), but later ones I got from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekend_Update#Timeline).

The task is simple. Given a range of years, output the initials of the person who was host during the most years in that time period. If there is a tie, output the initials of all the hosts that tied. Note that sometimes "Weekend Update" only has 1 host and sometimes it has 2.

For example, if the input is `1984-1985`, output `CG` because he was the only person to host during both of those years.

## Specifics

- Input is flexible, but it will always consist of a start year and a later end year. Also you don't need to include the first two digits of the year: `95-05` is fine for `1995-2005`.
- Assume all ranges are inclusive: `1982-1984` means `1982,1983,1984`.
- For input, the earliest start year is `1975` and the latest end year is `2017`

## Examples

- `1983-1987` => `DM` (he hosted '85,'86,'87`)
- `1999-2001` => `CQ JF TF` [`CQJFTF` also ok] (all hosted during two of those years)
- `1975-2017` => `SM` (has 9 years!)
- `1990-2000` => `KN NM` (both have 4 years)
- `2013-2015` => `SM CS CJ MC` (all have 2 years)

Comment: Hm, currently this challenge seems to be about who can encode the hosts + years the best. Have you considered having the hosts + years also as an input?

Comment: @StepHen Yeah, but I'm interested in how people are creative with encoding, and tried to make the names as short as possible as such.

Comment: I knew there was a tag for this, found it. I really thought there was also a tag for storing data like that efficiently, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @StepHen Are you thinking of Kolmogorov Complexity?

Comment: I guess that is what I am thinking of, although it doesn't quite match this challenge. I was always under the assumption that KC was for constant *output*, but I just checked the tag wiki and that's not what it says.

Comment: @JaneCurtain You're wrecking my compression scheme... O_o

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 291 bytes

```python
def f(b,e):
 s=''.join('A AB BC BCD BD BDE EFGH GHJ J JK KL L L L L L LM M M MN N N N O O OPQ PQ PQ PQ PQR QR QRS RS RS S S S S ST STUV UV UV UV'.split()[b-1975:e-1974]);C=s.count;return''.join({'CJDBCGBMCBCDKNCJTASCCMCCAMRMDGEHGMNMQFFPMSJC'[ord(h)-65::22]for h in s if C(h)==max(map(C,s))})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNb4JAEIbv/oq5wSZIAEspGA4wfAW6VMX2YjxohUBTgQAmNU1/O100VprnyWzyznuYbH3u8qpU@v6QZpDxeyElxgRak@PEj6ooec4CywYbmQ7Ygy64nh@AH4TAiCB6hhEULsRw5WVgsYSRK7iYwNU/1szXN7jJiW39WXQ82eynsq6pRjo8D1syR7MV36tT2c2btDs15e3Ubw5Dx0bfpsiOjWIM11aCSBEtuqKO7wY@jenS8xY0CZHbVM2Bz8n0UTUMRdlmVQM5FCW0UGSAbGOax90Xf9zVPAotIT@kr5ui7NgvyfrTTGBDI5N7pOuCIknyONJUFsn/W9LQku4RK8yGlkr6Xw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 325 bytes

```python
def f(x,y):a=sum([s.split(',')for s in('CC CC,JC JC,DA JC,DA,BM JC,BM JC,BM,CR CR,GM,BD,BD BD,MG,CE,BH BH BH,CG CG,'+'DM '*6+'DM,KN KN KN KN,'+'NM '*4+'CQ CQ CQ,'+'JF,TF '*4+'JF,TF,AP TF,AP TF,AP,SM AP,SM AP,'+'SM '*5+'SM,CS SM,CS,'+'CJ,MC '*4).split()[x-1975:y-1974]],[]);c=a.count;print{s for s in a if c(s)==max(map(c,a))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBBa4NAEIXv/RVz291mGjSJtSZ4iJPGYjG0sTfJYbGVCtVI1kBC6W83jqml8Phm3nvLwm59bj731aRt3z9yyOUJz2qufXMsZWrGpv4qGilQqHx/AANFJQUREGFEEBGulldiEPMyEGkLtMUwxmDVCTrGIdIjBk/QCykEClGMxCoGcXvPE583MIibDTezkaBX6MVZtMa39TXuV1y@wD9iEsMfu@MJX@HwREqgJ8cUYUx8i/p9oEpPd7bnOvMzj9luh@lOLTJfj7P9sWoW9aGomm8DwyeAhiKHTBrl@6U@yVLXMkOt1E@bS9t7mGIHV92w8TycWJZ9Na7TGXtoLG4sNl045cZR7QU)

#### 284 bytes, but more boring:

```python
def f(x,y):a=sum([s.split(',')for s in'eJx1z9sJwzAUBNFWtoBpwlrZCgrX+NV/LVEiHBxMYDjs79qyqVY1eeiS4j1O8SZvlCDllppR8Eh66BMuciGHbvGcdcYc+ua1R504Jv2RYdFF9tDV3/DexZVov26+ACfwONE='.decode('base64').decode('zip').split()[x-1975:y-1974]],[]);c=a.count;print{s for s in a if c(s)==max(map(c,a))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9Nb4JAFEX3/RXsmIlUGeRDNCxE1MZUTTSlReNiHIaKQRgZQLDpb6cQYzfv5tyzuY9V2SmJlbr2aSAEoJQqOMQWzy9gz7ucRWEGREmEQZIKXAhjkS5KdDf54nYff9ir2WeW2OwWpbvJd/rVWbm9d3cavtnl0nPO3DCv1dX1EKXhVj2j9WC7K6KJE0WMbQbTk67by5yE87djMSc@8Ugnx2ijyeqiUDaeP5uZmeP2ew4td25SKHpnPAlu69XUErs@JYlPgXjEnOqqCP@Le8gaeuyG@/IVmYY2rNpQDwdpf4AjYuEuSfI4G7E0jLMfLjx/E7AQBgIBHFrWBZfgghkgEobwtw4AMgd9qTkGfGnBNCVFltEDDK0B9DRya@QWmrLfGg3Wfw)

Comment: There's at least one secret you haven't found yet that saves a couple (or more) bytes.

Comment: @geokavel I can get down by 20 or so bytes I think. I'm trying to beat the "zip the text and decode it" approach but I haven't so far

Comment: @rosslh I don't think you saved your TIO link

Comment: fixed link: https://tio.run/##dY5Bb4JAEIXv/oq57W6ZGihSioaDjpWGZk0rvRkPhEpKgkhYSDRNfzsu2lpr0uTle5u3byZT7uuPbWG3be5zRgREGBKEhNPxiTiR3eOHSAugBQYSJ1Mt0JQB0iNOnuAopAAoQGawqQR24xrsea59YLC5PDm9wlEYzvBtBv8Qxy9wQYwknKmXR92ye4MhRRDpqyKkEKW@/5pM9FWZZzUXvfd1Cinf4V4MY181G75U338MmUi3FSjICsiXu1vLc53hvrPBaoXLlRglftxPtk1Rj6p13VTFp4LzRAxZCglXwvc38Y5v4pInmAvx1ZZVVtQ85Zb3YKOGK0TvN/M8vDNN60/mOjqzrnpm1zMvMl2xu54jRHsA

Comment: Interestingly, using the % formatting is the same length as [without the % formatting](https://tio.run/##XYzBboJAEIbvPsXcdrdODVSpRcNBxkpDs6aV3ggHQiUlASQsJpqmz05ZrNY2@fPN5Jt/tzo2H7ty3La5wxkREKFP4BMuFyeiK/VyJtIGaIOeRHfZBTpKD@kR3Sfog@QBeciGbCmB3dzric9rOEdf1voyGTJ6hT7a@St8W510v@LiBa6IgYQLu3qgv7D0RAqgp9bkoyT9ixipKs8aLgbv2xRSfsCjmMWO2hc8VD83hkykuxoUZCXk4eHWtKfW7KjHJIowjMQ8ceJRstuXzbzeNvu6/FRweRFDlkLClXCcIj7wIq54grkQX21VZ2XDU27aD2PsMBVi8OtsG@8Mw/zjplbnzH89Q/eMK9dVxrpnCdF@Aw)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>201</s> <s>200</s> 199 bytes

Takes the year range in currying syntax `(a)(b)`. Returns a string made of concatenated initials.

```js
a=>b=>"MCCJCSSMAPTFJFCQNMKNDMCGBHCEMGBDGMCRBMDAJCCC".match(/../g).reduce((o,c,n)=>(s=(a<(x-='0017240243612010012111'[n])?x:a)-(b<(y=+'3318464233612011012141'[n]+x)?b:y))>m?o:s<m?(m=s,c):c+o,m=x=2014)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>b=>"MCCJCSSMAPTFJFCQNMKNDMCGBHCEMGBDGMCRBMDAJCCC".match(/../g).reduce((o,c,n)=>(s=(a<(x-='0017240243612010012111'[n])?x:a)-(b<(y=+'3318464233612011012141'[n]+x)?b:y))>m?o:s<m?(m=s,c):c+o,m=x=2014)

console.log(f(1983)(1987)) // => DM
console.log(f(1999)(2001)) // => CQ JF TF
console.log(f(1975)(2017)) // => SM
console.log(f(1990)(2000)) // => KN NM
console.log(f(2013)(2015)) // => SM CS CJ MC
```